# Standard C++ library for large scale data processing

Tags: c++, nlp

Could you please let me know some of the standard library of C++ useful for processing large scale data for example Natural Language Processing with huge data set,data set of protein protein interactions etc.

Best,
Thetna

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) when dealing with huge volumes of data. Quoting from the website :

> STXXL implements containers and algorithms that can process huge volumes of data that only fit on disks. While the closeness to the STL supports ease of use and compatibility with existing applications, another design priority is high performance.

Also, the license is permissive :

> STXXL is free, open source, and available under the Boost Software License 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I like to add the [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) Library as a non commercial (BSD-Style licensing) alternative:

> The HDF5 technology suite includes:
>
> ```
> - A versatile data model that can represent very complex data objects 
>   and a wide variety of metadata.
> - A completely portable file format with no limit on the number or size of data
>   objects in the collection.
> - A software library that runs on a range of computational platforms, from 
>   laptops to massively parallel systems, and implements
>   a high-level API with C, C++, Fortran 90, and Java interfaces.
> - A rich set of integrated performance features that allow for access 
>   time and storage space optimizations.
> - Tools and applications for managing, manipulating, viewing, and 
>   analyzing the data in the collection.
> ```